# How to reinstall soffit receptacles securely

Tags: receptacle

Hoping someone can offer an easy fix for this as I'm not very handy. These outlets at my mom's house keep falling out of the soffit. I push them in and they within days they're back down. The soffit is wood. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you have here are "old work" boxes. There are tabs on the top and bottom that are supposed to secure the boxes in place (see picture below) You'll have to turn off the power and remove the white cover from the box. Then turn the screws at the top and bottom counterclockwise. This will lower the tab and move it to the back of the box. Insert the box back into the hole and turn the screws clockwise. This will raise the tab and draw it in to secure the box in place. If by chance the tabs are broken off, then you'll have to replace the box with a new one.

[image]

Comment: The box in the soffit looks very much like the current product on the shelves in stores. If the tabs are broken or missing, I'd consider transferring the screw and tab from a new box onto the existing box rather than fully swapping the boxes. Transferring the screw and tab takes just a couple seconds with an electric screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an old work box I see the screw on the right bottom of the box there should be another in upper left of the photo.

The cover needs to be removed and if the tabs are on the screws unscrew them an inch both sides then place the box back in the hole,

with the box in the hole try to tighten the 2 screws until snug , if the tabs are ok when you tighten the tabs will open and snug up, this will fix the problem unless the tabs are stripped or broken.

If stripped or broken tabs the box will need to be replaced with a new “old work box” requiring the power to be turned off for this circuit the receptacle to be removed the wires pulled out of the box and a new old work box installed.